# create context variable from node red to watson conversation

Tags: node-red, watson-conversation

Is it possible to send a variable to watson conversation?

This is simply what I'm trying to do. Get Slack Username
Save the username as a context variable
When the user talks to the chatbot it will say, **Hello username** without the need for a user input.

I have read about additional_context but I cannot seem to find anywhere how to use it. This is my function that processes the slack text before it goes to Watson conversation

```
msg._payload = msg.payload;
msg.payload = msg._payload.event.text; 
msg.additional_context = msg._payload.event.user
node.send(msg); // Send the message long to the next node
```

If I look in the debug node, the additional_context key returns the user Id correctly, But I don't know how to "fetch" it from inside a Conversation node.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You normally shouldn't be using `node.send(msg)` in function node, `return msg` is the usual way send the msg to the next node.

Answer (score 0):

To add additional variable means to add the variable in the `"context"` part of the message request. When sending the POST message to Watson Assistant (Conversation) API add the variable as follow:

`{
   "input": {
       "text" : "Text the user typed."
    }
    "context" : {
        "username" : "user name",
        ...+all of the attributes of the context sent in the the last response from WA
    }
}`

Just remember - at the beginning of the conversation it is ok to send an empty `context` or a `context` containing only the username variable. However, as the conversation starts, the system sends its state in the `context` field, so it is important to send this context back in the next POST message request (as the system is state-less and the state is held in the context object). It is ok to add additional variables from node.js to this context though.

More info about POST message here: [API documentation](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/assistant/api/v1/curl.html?curl#message) (23.10.2018)